# Docker build - failed to compute cache key: "/srv/app/www" not found: not found

Tags: windows, macos, docker

I'm having a lot of difficulty getting docker to work on osx.  I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.17.0-alpine AS staging
CMD ["mkdir","/srv/app"]
WORKDIR /srv/app
COPY . .
RUN ["npm","install"]

FROM node:10.17.0-alpine AS builder
RUN ["mkdir", "/srv/app" ]
COPY --from=staging /srv/app/ /srv/app/
WORKDIR /srv/app
WORKDIR /srv/app
RUN ["npm","run-script","build-staging"]

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /srv/app/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I call this file like so: `docker build -f ./Dockerfile --no-cache -t <my-app>:staging .`

In windows this works perfectly, but my team has a mix of Windows and OSX computers, and docker build fails on all of our OSX machines with this error:

```
=> ERROR [stage-2 2/3] COPY --from=builder /srv/app/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/                                                             
------                                                                                                                                               
 > [stage-2 2/3] COPY --from=builder /srv/app/www/ /usr/share/nginx/html/:                                                                           
------                                                                                                                                               
failed to compute cache key: "/srv/app/www" not found: not found
```

I came across a possible cause of the situation where I could try adding to "* text=auto" to my .gitattributes file but this didn't fix the issue even after recloning my repo.

How is it possible for my Dockerfile to work on Windows and not on OSX?

EDIT: I should add that I have a nearly identical project with an identical Docker file whose docker push works on all Windows machines and all OSX machines.

Comment: Git isn't involved here; it's pretty clear that the problem is that `/srv/app/www` does not exist at that point, but what's not clear is why not: `WORKDIR` supposedly has a recursive mkdir built in to it. I don't know why you have two of them in the `FROM ... AS builder` section, and they're too far down *in* that section, and some errors should happen sooner if `/srv` does not exist, but that would be my guess: that `/srv` does not exist and somehow that's messing with the rest of it.

Comment: @torek - I'm still learning to use Docker, and this project isinherited from a previous developer whose no longer with my company, so I wouldn't be surprised if the Dockerfile could be cleaned up a bit.  What I'm hung up on in two things though:
 - My docker push for this project works on all Windows machines and fails on all OSX machines.
 - I have a nearly identical project with an identical Docker file whose docker push works on all Windows machines and all OSX machines.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue.  My docker memory and swap resources available were too small for the project in question.  The error message provided by Docker was not very helpful in the case and docker build was getting interrupted once docker reached its memory limit.

Comment: Ah, this now makes sense (including the fact that the error message doesn't, make sense that is  ): all is going well, then some inner setup thing dies unexpectedly, then `/srv` (or something within it) gets unmounted and the outer part that reports the error is trying to find the error but it's gone.